# Bidirectional communication between python and js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have develop webpage using HTML and javascript. I need to pass the input values as argument to python backend using nodejs.can anyone help me with better solution?

Comment: Please search, this has maybe been answered before, and then edit your question to show us what you tried and why this didn't worked.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to start the Python script with the values as arguments, you could do this.

```
var spawn = require("child_process").spawn;
var pythonProcess = spawn('python',["path/to/script.py", arg1, arg2, ...]);
```

If the script is already running, another option is to use socket programming.